# Header-only linking

Tags: c++, c, linker

Many C++ projects (e.g. many `Boost` libraries) are "header-only linked".

Is this possible also in plain `C`? How to put the source code into headers? Are there any sites about it?

Comment: You do it exactly the same way as in C++. Header inclusion is a C preprocessor feature.

Comment: But you have all those static functions and public functions, I guess it's not that easy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Executive summary: You can, but you shouldn't.**

C and C++ code is *preprocessed* before it's compiled: all headers are "pasted" into the source files that include them, recursively. If you define a function in a header and it is included by two C files, you will end up with two copies in each object file ([One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) violation).

You can create "header-only" C libraries if all your functions are marked as `static`, that is, not visible outside the translation unit. But it also means you will get a copy of all the static functions in each translation unit that includes the header file.

It is a bit different in C++: inline functions are not `static`, symbols emitted by the compiler are still visible by the linker, but the linker can discard duplicates, rather than giving up ("weak" symbols).

It's not idiomatic to write C code in the headers, unless it's based on macros (e.g. [`queue(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/queue)). In C++, the main reason to keep code in the headers are templates, which may result in code instantiation for different template parameters, which is not applicable to C.

Answer (score 4):

You do not link headers.

In C++ it's slightly easier to write code that's already better-off in headers than in separately-compiled modules because templates require it. <sup>1</sup>

But you can also use the `inline` keyword for functions, which exists in C as well as C++. <sup>2</sup>

```
// Won't cause redefinition link errors, because of 6.7.4/5
inline void foo(void) {
   // ...
}
```

> `[c99: 6.7.4/5:]` A function declared with an `inline` function
>   specifier is an *inline function*. **The function specifier may appear
>   more than once; the behavior is the same as if it appeared only once.**
>   Making a function an inline function suggests that calls to the
>   function be as fast as possible. The extent to which such
>   suggestions are effective is implementation-defined.

You're a bit stuck when it comes to data objects, though.

---

<sup>1</sup> - Sort of.
<sup>2</sup> - C99 for sure. C89/C90 I'd have to check.

Comment: Did you mean static keyword? Because inline is only a recommendation to the compiler and can be ignored completely.

Comment: @James: No, I meant `inline`. Although `inline` is only a hint and the compiler is not required to physically inline the function, the effect that it has on the function's linkage _is_ well-defined, and _must_ be observed by an implementation. Otherwise how could you ever tell what linkage your `inline` function had?

Comment: Oh I see, it's different in C vs. C++, isn't it?

Comment: @James: No, it's completely the same in every way. The compiler may not completely ignore the `inline` keyword; it merely is allowed not to physically inline the function. Note the difference between "`inline`" and "inline". :)

Comment: @Tomalak: for data objects in C++, not stuck but pretty darn inconvenient. you can always use the "template trick" for extern linkage data in header file. cheers,

Answer (score 4):

Boost makes heavy use templates and template meta-programming which you cannot emulate (all that easily) in C.

But you can of course cheat by having declarations and code in C headers which you `#include` but that is not the same thing.  I'd say *"When in Rome..."* and program C as per C conventions with libraries.

Comment: I find the "When in Rome..." saying as a great answer. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad to be of help. Feel free to accept it too, provided you still see it as the best answer when reviewing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is quite possible. Declare all functions in headers and either all as `static` or just use a single compilation unit (i.e. only a single c file) in your projects.

As a personal anecdote, I know quite a number of physicists who insist that this technique is the only true way to program C. It is beneficial because it's the poor man's version of `-fwhole-program`, i.e. makes optimizations based on the knowledge of function behaviour possible. It is practical because you don't need to learn about using the linker flags. It is a bad idea because your whole program must be compiled as a whole and recompiled with each minor change.

Personally, I'd recommend to let it be or at least go with `static` for only a few functions.

Comment: Answer does not point out the glaring hole with this approach.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Which of the glaring holes?

Comment: `static` gives you per-TU copies. Really, the holes that all the other answers mention.